# Managing connections to multiple databases on different servers

Tags: c#, .net, connection-pooling

I am building a web application that needs to talk to databases on multiple servers. I came up with the idea of holding all the connection strings in Web.config and creating a dictionary in my DBUtility class to hold connections, with Key as the DB name and Value as the connection object.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="+++++++++" providerName="System.Data.Odbc" connectionString="+++++++++"/>
    <add name="---------" providerName="System.Data.Odbc" connectionString="---------"/>
    <add name="|||||||||" providerName="System.Data.Odbc" connectionString="|||||||||"/>
    <add name="*********" providerName="System.Data.Odbc" connectionString="*********"/>
    <add name="~~~~~~~~~" providerName="System.Data.Odbc" connectionString="~~~~~~~~~"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Each of those connection strings is unique(either connect to different databases on the same server or to a database in another server altogether). I am able to successfully connect to these databases although I am not sure about a couple of things I am doing in my code.

```
public class DBUtil{
    private static Dictionary<string, OdbcConnection> connections = new Dictionary<string, OdbcConnection>();

    // open connection
    private bool OpenConnection(string name)
    {
         OdbcConnection connection;
        try
        {
            if (!connections.ContainsKey(name))
            {
                connection = new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[name].ConnectionString);
                connections.Add(name, connection);
            }
            else
            {
                connection = connections[name];
            }
            connection.Open();
        }
        catch
        {
            //connections[name] = null;
            throw;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Am I right to hold these connections in a dictionary and use them as I have? Is there a better/more efficient way to achieve this? I also read about connection pooling [here](http://www.pythian.com/blog/sql-server-understanding-and-controlling-connection/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058591/net-sqlconnection-class-connection-pooling-and-reconnection-logic). From my understanding a new connection pool is created for every unique connection string and my usage of dictionary should not interfere with connection pooling. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: It just makes no sense to me to create a new connection if ConnectionState.Closed and even less sense to do nothing with it.

Comment: That's right. I will get that correct! Thanks!

Comment: OK now you check for open versus null.  How does a connection of null for connection that would not open do your web site any good?

Comment: I am sorry. I am not sure I understand your question. What I intend to do is to check if a connection with the given name exists already and if it does, open it. Else create it, add it and then open it.

Comment: And if Open fails you just null out the connection.  How is your web site going to function if a connection it needs is null?

Comment: Sorry, I actually meant to comment that line out. Does that make it better?

Comment: Did not realise clicking on the move to chat link will add a comment here. Nevertheless chat is blocked on my office comp so would be nice if we could continue here.

Comment: But I don't have anything to chat about.  I appears to me you have not given the problem much thought nor much effort on the initial question.

Comment: The whole thing is pointless. You should create new connection objects in your code and allow .NET to re-use existing database connections as it sees fit. You are re-inventing the wheel here.